# Referencing dynamically changing items in cvlist

Tags: cv, currvita, refcount

In an academic CV, I want to flexibly refer to cv list items when I add items to this list. Specifically, I want to refer to the item number of a publication elsewhere, and when I update my list of publications, the reference should automatically get updated. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[roman]{parnotes}
\newcounter{publicationNo}
\stepcounter{publicationNo} % increase number of publicationNo from 0 to 1
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
    #2%
    \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection\label{#1}\endgroup
}
\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{Your candidate}
\begin{cvlist}{Publications}
\item[\namedlabel{paper1}{\arabic{publicationNo}}] Your candidate: paper 1
\stepcounter{publicationNo}\item[\namedlabel{draft1}{\arabic{publicationNo}}] Also, this is under review
\stepcounter{publicationNo}\item[\namedlabel{paper2}{\arabic{publicationNo}}] Your candidate: paper 2 
\stepcounter{publicationNo}\item[\namedlabel{draft2}{\arabic{publicationNo}}] Also, this is under review
\end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
I had one great idea (\ref{paper2}). I build on it for another great idea (\ref{draft1}).
```

I've been building on [this suggestion](https://texblog.org/2012/03/21/cross-referencing-list-items/) but it does not seem to transfer from descriptions to cv lists. I suspect a solution to my problem is somewhere implicit in [this exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334152/cross-reference-the-number-in-enumerate-environment) but I was unable to make it work for me -- I do not want hyperlinks in my document. Apologies if I have overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly,

`\label` picks up the last `refstepcounter` value.

The label for an item (like *, or a number) is different from the label for a `\ref` to refer to.

Set the item label to publicationNo, and `refstep` the publicationNo for `\label` to pick it up.

[image: ref counter]

Doing the `\label`ling inside the item label didn't seem to work.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[roman]{parnotes}
\newcounter{publicationNo}
\setcounter{publicationNo}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{Your candidate}
\begin{cvlist}{Publications}
\refstepcounter{publicationNo}
\item[\arabic{publicationNo}] \label{paper1} Your candidate: paper 1 -- 
\refstepcounter{publicationNo}
\item[\arabic{publicationNo}] \label{draft1} Also, this is under review: draft1
\refstepcounter{publicationNo}
\item[\arabic{publicationNo}] \label{paper2} Your candidate: paper 2 -- see \ref{paper1}
\refstepcounter{publicationNo}
\item[\arabic{publicationNo}] \label{draft2} Also, this is under review: draft2
\end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
I had one great idea (\ref{paper2})=item3. I build on it for another great idea (\ref{draft1})=item2.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks! This even works when you end and restart the cvlist.